# Convert these json_encoded characters to normal: class=\"timestamp\">test\u003c\/abbr> \u00b7 \u003cspan class

Tags: php, javascript, character, json

Well I'm getting a json encoded with PHP plain text and its coming like this
how do I get the html parsed with PHP, is there any function to do this?

This is how I get:              `class=\"timestamp\">test\u003c\/abbr> \u003cspan class`

This is how its supposed to be: `class="timestamp">test</abbr> <span class`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: json_decode actually converts the string into an array

Comment: because you are probably passing an encoded array. but you can always get $json_decoded[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a few duplicate questions on how to use [`preg_preplace('#\\u[a-f0-9]{4}#)`](http://php.net/preg_preplace)) and [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) to convert the `\u1234` Unicode escapes. But can't find it..

But in your case you also have other quotes backslashed, why it would be possible to use this lazy appraoch:

```
 $string = json_decode('"' . $string . '"');
```